# Automatic updates to free OpenJDK on Windows?

Tags: windows-10, jdk

How do I install or setup a free JDK such as OpenJDK on Windows 10 in such a way that it will automatically hint about or install security updates to the JDK?

Is there some distribution except for the OracleJdk that includes an updater?

Comment: "it will automatically hint about or install security updates to the JDK?" - This does not exist.  "Is there some distribution except for the OracleJdk that includes an updater?" - No

Comment: There is a currently open issue for this for [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/): ["Create autoupdater for AdoptOpenJDK binaries"](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-installer/issues/4)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html) pre-built binaries (as they have long-term support and they are very close to "reference" Java implementation. Besides, they also provide JRE builds, which is less common.

Currently they don't have an automatic update tool (although they have the [ticket](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-installer/issues/4)), but there is a third-party [AdoptOpenJDK Update Watcher](https://github.com/tushev/aojdk-updatewatcher) that does the job (for Windows). If you don't have JDK/JRE installed yet, it can also download and install it for you.
[image: AdoptOpenJDK Update Watcher]

Answer (score 1):

[OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)
is now maintained by the community, as Oracle has abandoned free support.
Updates are done by volunteers on an irregular schedule, so there is no mechanism
for automatic updates.

If you wish to be alerted automatically when a new release is available,
you may use a free service that alerts by email when a webpage is updated,
such as for example [visualping](https://visualping.io/).

You could for example set up an alert for the github page of
[ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild)
(but the page may change in the future).